# Celery run task after another tasks with subtasks complete

Tags: celery

I know about celery chain.
So I can run one task after completion of another easily (without taking arguments):

```
chain(task1.si(), task2.si())()
```

But I have a bit more complicated structure:

```
                  task1 -- task2
                 /  |  \
             sub1 sub2 sub3
```

I want to run `task2` only after completion of `task1` and all it's subtasks.
Now, my `task2` runs just after completion `task1`

Is it possible?